# Jsonp cross-domain ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm working on an application which use ajax call to get html from the server. 
When I run it on the server, everything works fine.

But when I'm running on a localhost, I've a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. 
I looked arround and it seems like using jsonp could be the solution.

So, my ajax call looks like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
        // should put the data in a div
    },
    error: function(){
        //do some stuff with errors
    }
});
```

I get html from the server, but I always have this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Is there a way to wrap the jsonp response in html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use JSONP to grab an HTML document. You need to wrap your HTML in a JavaScript variable. JSONP has some very specific requirements to make it work properly, including a callback function/attribute. If you're not in control of the server hosting the target page, you won't be able to make it work. This is a security precaution to prevent a random page from  being able to steal your personal information from sites you're logged into via an AJAX call.

**UPDATE**

I read your question more thoroughly. It sounds like your problem is that you're in a development environment that doesn't have the resource in question. JSONP isn't the answer because it's a lot of trouble to get running just to make your page work in development. You should create a local copy of the target HTML and grab it using a relative or server-absolute URL such as `"/the/page/i/need.html"` instead of `"http://myserver.com/the/page/i/need.html"`

Comment: @GuillaumeleFloch You're running your production site on `localhost`? You said it works fine "on the server".

Comment: Yes, I developped the applciation first on the server. But now, I want to wrapped it as a mobile applciation that's why I'm testing it on the local host..

Comment: So why is the resource you're trying to grab via JSONP in a different origin (server) than the page your grabbing it for?

Comment: So I've html on a distant server. I used django for the server. From this server I do some ajax calls to get html data and query my database. 
But I want to be able to do that from a localhost. Basically, I want to wrap my application in phongap. Once the application will be 'native', the calls won't come from my server to my server.. That's why I want to be able to get my data from the localhost

Comment: Okay, yeah, you're probably after JSONP, then. But you'll need to wrap your HTML in JavaScript to make it work. Go look up a JSONP tutorial and follow its instructions, but create an object to return that's something like `{"htmlSnippet":"<div><span>...</span></div>"}`. Just make sure that you escape any quotes in your HTML.

Comment: Ok so I need to make changes on the server, and then on the client, I can get the html by parsing the JSONP? right?

Comment: Have you see a particular Jsonp tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data by jsonp, then the server side need to support jsonp.

There is no way just change the `dataType` to get the data.

If the server side doesn't support jsonp, then you need to make a proxy in your localhost.

Comment: The fact is, I get the data back.. but with a 'Syntax error'.. So all the code is on the client side.. but I'm not able to use it.

Comment: @GuillaumeleFloch Yes, you could get the data back in some meanings, and it must cause Syntax error, check how jsonp works.

Comment: @GuillaumeleFloch The reason you're getting the syntax error is that JSONP makes use of a dynamically attached `<script>` tag to include the target JSONP resource. Since you're essentially telling the browser that your HTML page is a JavaScript resource, it is giving you a JavaScript error as it attempts to parse HTML as JavaScript.

Comment: But is there any other way to do something with the jsonp? or a way to make cross domain ajax calls to get html?

Comment: @GuillaumeleFloch No, see my answer below. It's a security precaution and getting around it without the explicit "consent" granted by a JSONP resource would be considered a security vulnerability.

Comment: But I means, is there a way to do ajax call cross domain? without jsonp?